# How to send curl request with post data imported from a file

Tags: linux, http, curl, command-line-interface

I have a curl command like below which works fine and I get the response back. I am posting json data to an endpoint which gives me response back after hitting it.

```
curl -v 'url' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Origin: url' --data-binary '{"query":"\n{\n  data(clientId: 1234, filters: [{key: \"o\", value: 100}], key: \"world\") {\n    title\n    type\n    pottery {\n      text\n      pid\n      href\n      count\n      resource\n    }\n  }\n}"}' --compressed
```

Now I am trying to read the binary data from `temp.json` file outside but somehow it doesn't work and I get an error -

```
curl -v 'url' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Origin: url' --data-binary "@/Users/david/Downloads/temp.json" --compressed
```

I have stored json in below `temp.json` file -

```
{
  data(clientId: 1234, filters: [{key: "o", value: 100}], key: "world") {
    title
    type
    pottery {
      text
      pid
      href
      count
      resource
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error I am getting -

```
.......
* upload completely sent off: 211 out of 211 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< date: Fri, 28 May 2021 23:38:12 GMT
< server: envoy
< content-length: 0
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1
<
* Connection #0 to host url left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

Is there anything wrong in my above curl command?

**Update**

If I copy the exact same content in the `temp.json` file that I have in my original curl with `\n` then it works fine. So looks like that is the issue.

It means I need to find a way to convert new lines to `\n` manually from `temp.json` before sending the curl request or is there any other way?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your curl command. I do see something wrong with the `temp.json` file. Doesn't look like valid Json to me (unless there is some new 'json dialect' I'm not aware of). That "Internal Server Error" could very well be the server not being able to parse the Json file since it's not in proper Json format.

Comment: yeah sorry it's not a valid json (I should have made it clear) but it is the exact same request we sent in the binary data as it is in the curl request. I just copy pasted the request that I have in my original curl command line into a file by removing all `\n` from it. Do you think removing all `\n` from it is causing this issue?

Comment: It should not cause the issue. In fact, a well formed json can perfectly be a one-liner, without any line break whatsoever. I have no clue what's going on there. Is it your own API and you have a way to check the server error logs to check out what's exactly the issue it encounters? Or is it an external service you're using?

Comment: If I copy the exact same content in the temp.json file that I have in my original curl with `\n` then it works fine. So looks like that is the issue. It means I need to find a way to convert new lines to `\n` manually before sending the curl request or is there any other way?

Comment: Before anything else, can you try to change from `--data-binary` to `--data-raw` to use the json file? I'm now on my Linux machine (yesterday I was on Windows and couldn't really try) and trying `--data-raw '@/path/to/file.json'` is working well, no need to put those `\n` in the json file.